# How can I snap on a line, but not a corner?

Tags: inkscape, snapping

Sometimes I want to snap on a line in inkscape, but I do not want to snap on a corner. This happens when I want to draw a line from a rectilinear shape and the line begins on the shape near a corner, but not on the corner.

If I have snapping on, then it snaps to the corner, but if I have snapping off, then it is hard to connect the new line to the shape.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Enable the following snapping options, and disable all the others.

- Enable Snapping
- Snap Nodes, Paths and Handles
- Snap to Paths

Here's the result

[image]